# Concurrent chained javascript promises

Tags: javascript, concurrency, promise, es6-promise

I have javascript promises A and C where B is a function that returns a promise. This is how I'd like them to flow:

```
A--->B--->
C-------->
          D------>
```

B utilizes output from A, and D utilizes output from B and C

My current code looks roughly as so:

```
var runPromises = [];
runPromises.push(A.then(B));
runPromises.push(C);

Promise.all(runPromises).then(values => console.log(values));
```

What I'm seeing happen is A and C execute but B does not until after A and C are logged out. What is the proper pattern here for execution? Do A and B need to be put in an encompassing promise?

> To add on to my original question to explain Jaromanda's correct answer: My B function was defined roughly as so:

```
var B = function(inputA){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        http.get(site, function(done){
            inputA['site'] = done;
        }
    resolve(inputA);
```

This was resolving inputA before the http.get could return and enrich inputA.

Comment: Your code is correct - please provide more information about promises A and C, and probably the most important definition of function B - I suspect function B is not returning a promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if A, B and C are promises, then `A.then(B)` will return A as the result. The argument to `.then` must be FUNCTION, not a promise

What you want to do is something like

```
Promise.all([A.then(result=>B), C]).then(values => console.log(values));
```

> If B is a FUNCTION (as per the comment below) rather than a PROMISE (as per the question), it's a simple change:

```
Promise.all([A.then(result=>B()), C]).then(values => console.log(values));
//---------------------------^^
```

or more simply

```
Promise.all([A.then(B), C]).then(values => console.log(values));
```

which is basically what you had in the question - so I'm now confused as to what the problem is? Is it the values shown in the console.log?

```js
var delay = (timeout, value) => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {resolve(value); console.log('done', value);}, timeout); 
    console.log('begin', value)
});


var A = delay(3000, 'valueOfA'); // A is a Promise
var C = delay(2000, 'valueOfC'); // C is a Promise
var B = valA => {
    console.log('B called with', valA);
    return delay(1000, valA + ':valueOfB'); // include valA to show that the resolved value of B depends on the resolved value of A
} // B is a function that returns a Promise and uses the resolved value of A as input
Promise.all([A.then(B),C]).then(values => console.log(values));
```

Comment: Jaromanda, I apologize I should've specified that B is a function that returns a promise. That said, the solution you proposed does not appear to work for me. Instead of returning A and C's results, it returns the B function and C's results.

Comment: of course the result is B and C, those are the two promises you **NEED** to wait for before continuing with D, B doesn't get executed until A completes - this matches the diagram in your question 100%. The only flaw in your original question was that you were using `.then` wrong.

Comment: But C is a fulfilled promise when console.log is run whereas B is just returning the function. I'm trying to determine how to have B also be a fulfilled promise so I can get the results of promise's B and C before console.log executes.

Comment: is B a promise or a function that returns a promise? what about A and C - perhaps you need to be more clear in the question. You SAY they are Promises in the question

Comment: My apologies, I updated the question right before commenting on your answer. B is a function that returns a promise but the updated answer you provided now returns "undefined" instead of function.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Your original code is correct if B is a function. so the question really is, why does B wait for C to complete?

Comment: Hahaha that's why I'm confused too. I need both B and C's results for D to run. I don't need B to wait on C to complete though. David's answer appears to work in the example he created but I don't understand the subtle difference between his code and mine. And to comment on your edited answer, yes, the values shown in console log return A's fulfilled promise and C's fulfilled promise but B's fulfilled promise is not returned in the console.log

Comment: `the values shown in console log return A's fulfilled promise and C's fulfilled promise` - with my code, that's **IMPOSSIBLE** - added a snippet to demonstrate

Comment: By the way, the upshot is, that there was nothing wrong with your original code - function B get called with the resolved value of promise A and returns a Promise. `Promise.all` waits for both B() and C to be resolved, the console.log should log the correct promises. This all points to the definitions of `promise A`, `function B` or `promise C` being incorrect. As you have not provided this information, one can only guess what the real problem is

Comment: Turns out that my B function was resolving with the exact same values as A's passed in data before my HTTP calls in B were able to enrich A's data. Doh! Thanks for all the help Jaromanda!

Answer (score 1):

To chain promises, you can use [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), but the parameter needs to be a **function** that returns the next Promise. The correct code would be:

```
var runPromises = [];
runPromises.push(A.then(() => B));
runPromises.push(C);

Promise.all(runPromises).then(values => console.log(values));
```

Comment: 4castle, as I just mentioned to Jaromanda, I apologize I should've specified that B is a function that returns a promise. That said, the solution you proposed gives the same results as Jaromanda's and does not appear to work for me. Instead of returning A and C's results, it returns the B function itself and C's results.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other answers, if we assume "B" is a function that sets up a promise, and not a promise itself, you are correct that "B" should execute without relying on "C". You can prove this out with a small test:

```
let start = Date.now();
function debug(p) {
  p.then((r) => {
    let secs = ((Date.now() - start) / 1000).toFixed(2)
    console.log(secs + "s: " + r);
  });
}

let a = new Promise((r) => {
  setTimeout(r, 0, "a done");
});
debug(a);

let b = a.then((res) => {
  return new Promise((r) => {
    setTimeout(r, 0, res + ":b done");
  });
});
debug(b);

let c = new Promise((r) => {
  setTimeout(r, 1000, "c done");
});
debug(c);

Promise.all([b, c]).then((res) => {
  console.log("result: " + JSON.stringify(res));
});
```

Results in:

```
0.00s: a done
0.01s: a done:b done
1.00s: c done
result: ["a done:b done","c done"]
```

Comment: Btw, `setTimeout` accepts the callback function parameters, so you can simplify your calls to `setTimeout(r, 1000, "c done");`

Comment: nice, @zerkms, I didn't know that : ). Updated answer.

Comment: David, thanks for the response -- I entirely understand your code and it works fine but don't understand why it functions differently than mine. If I'm passing in a.then(b) in place of where you pass in b (that is doing a.then(function_i've_defined_as_b), whats the difference?

Comment: I'm certainly not opposed to writing it this way if it's the proper way to do it syntactically but it seems like the code would look much cleaner if I could keep B from exclusively relying on A in it's definition and instead did something along the lines of a.then(b) in the Promise.all